# column values into one string in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have and address table with the following columns:

- addressId
- buildingName
- streetNo
- streetName
- streetType
- subAddressNo
- subAddressType
- suburb
- postCode
- state

What I want is to `SELECT * from address where addressId = @addressId`, and that return would be all columns concatenated into one string.  Something like:

```
set @addressString = (SELECT * from address where addressId = @addressId)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select coalesce(cast(addressId as varchar)+ ',', '')  + coalesce(buildingName+ ',', '') 
coalesce(cast(streetNo as varchar)+ ',', '') -- + and so on 
from address
```

remember to cast the numeric types as varchar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT buldingName + ' ' + streetNo + ' ' + streetName + ' ' + theRestOfYourColumns AS ClientAddress
FROM YourAddressTable
WHERE addressId = @addressIdPreviouslyAssignedVariable
```

Comment: I know this probably goes without saying, but I just didn't type out all of the column names, but use any configuration you would like.